# Media query not working as it should

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm testing my website on different screens and devices and all is working well except for Ipads.

The media queries are like this:

```
 /* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    .container {
        width: 250px;
   }
}
/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) {
    .container {
        width: 250px;
   }
}
/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    .container {
        width: 250px;
   }
}
/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
    .container {
        width: 700px;
   }
}
/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    .container {
        width: 700px;
   }
}
/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    .container {
        width: 700px;
   }
}
```

When I test it on an Ipad, instead of 700px, the container is 250px (smartphones landscape media query). I've tested it in many sites and none of them is giving me the right container value (700px).

However, I own a small computer (a Toshiba Notebook to be more specific) and I tested the website there and the container is 700px when it's supposed to be 250px!

Can anyone tell me whats happening?

Comment: Try giving the body a background color and check if the media query is working properly...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) {
    .container {
        width: 250px;
   }
```

}
    /* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */

you don't have here upper condition i.e max-width: 500px and browser mixes this media query and media query for iPad.

Comment: I'm using this example http://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints

Comment: Try to give upper condition.